# Laravel 8 de programacion web

Tags: laravel-8, laragon

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes a todos tengo una consulta sobre un trabajo de laravel8, uso también cmder y el laragon.
El trabajo me funciona en estos "http://portfolio.test/public/portfolio/quis" con "public" pero durante todo este tiempo y la forma correcta es "http://portfolio.test/portfolio/quis".

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo soluciono este problema de la url o donde tengo que hacer modificaciones para que me acepte http://portfolio.test/portfolio/quis y NO http://portfolio.test/public/portfolio/quis, al cual esto estaría mal para mi proyecto?

Answer (score 1):

te comento, cuando arranqué con laravel tuve el mismo problema. Y resulta que se soluciona cuando subas el proyecto al hosting, ahí podés configurar que el "directorio raiz" sea la carpeta "public".

En mi caso como entorno local uso "xampp" y configuré el virtualhost para que tome como "directorio raíz" también la carpeta "public".

Espero te sirva, ya que de esta forma te ahorrás tener que modificar archivos .htaccess y/o php.ini

Saludos y próspero año nuevo!